# URL get response error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have the following lines in my Rails controller code

```
url_parsed = URI.parse(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_parsed)
```

When I passed `www.google.com` as `url`, it gave

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000002e07908 URL:www.google.com>
```

on the second line, even though I don't call  the method `request_uri` anywhere.

In this case, I'd like it to show my nice error page, instead of this ugly error. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `url` string is missing a protocol: `url="http://www.google.com"`

Then your code will return `Net::HTTPOK` - see this [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPOK.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make it show my error page in this case, instead of its (ugly) error